# My Merge Sort algorithm don't get a correct answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I an new to C++ and algorithm.I am confused at Merge Sort algorithm which I write. I don't know why the code don't get correct answer when it has no errors. In the code, I wanna to sort 5 numbers I input. but the sorted arrays doesn't print on screen. I want to know the problems in my code. Thanks a lot.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int merge(int a[], int low, int mid, int high) {
    int h = low; int j = mid + 1; int k = low;
    int *b = new int[high - low + 1];
    while ((h <= mid) && (j <= high)) {
        if (a[h] < a[j])
            b[k++] = a[h++];
        else
            b[k++] = a[j++];

    }
    if (h > mid) {
        for (j; j <= high;++j)
            b[k++]=a[j];
    }
    if (j > high) {
        for (h; h <= mid; ++h)
            b[k++] = a[h];
    }
    for (int i = low; i <= high; ++i)
        a[i] = b[i];
    delete []b;
    return 0;
}
int MergeSort(int a[], int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        MergeSort(a, low, mid);
        MergeSort(a, mid + 1, high);
        merge(a, low, mid, high);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int const n(5);
    int a[n];
    cout << "Input " << n << " numbers please:";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    MergeSort(a, 0, n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; ++i)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ?

Comment: @Amier could you tell which input is giving you wrong answer?? code seems to work fine on my system..!

Comment: Just because some code passes through the compiler without errors doesn't mean it has to be correct. There are many possibilities for *undefined behavior* or other *logical errors*. First of all you should turn on more warnings, and fix those as if they were errors. Then you should learn how to use a debugger and how to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables.

Comment: @ H.G I debug my code in my mind.I try to debug it in VS, but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Amier You don't see that "Debug" menu in the Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: @Amier Also, if you quit using `new[]` and used `std::vector` along with `at()`, you will see you're [going out of bounds](http://ideone.com/HZ9SxV).  And since you're using Visual Studio, you don't even need to use `at()`, as the debug runtime will tell you you're going out of bounds.

Comment: @FReeze FRancis  For example,i input 5 4 2 3 1. The output is only 1,it seems to figure out the next number. But the MergeSort.exe is broken soon.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I know how to step through my code line by line. But i don't monitor the variables. I am trying to do that now.

Comment: @Amier Change the call from `new[]` to `std::vector` as in the example I linked to.  You could have  saved yourself a lot of time if you used the proper container class instead of resorting to `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: The reason it isn't printing is because it's stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank for all reply.  I run my code successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MergeSort` function - assume `low + 1 == high` thus `mid==low`.

Recursive call with `MergeSort(a, low, mid)` will return immediately, while `MergeSort(a, mid, high)` will be passing again the same `low` and `high` - until your application will overflow the stack (and you'll post again a question on SO?)

---

`merge` function, assume `low==3`, `mid==4`, `high==5`.

You allocate a `b[]` of `3`. So far so good.

But then you start with `k=low` (which is 3) and perform the assignment of `b[k++]` - already out of bounds even more at the next steps when you'll be writing at `b[4]` and `b[5]` (while `b[0]` and `b[1]` will stay untouched).

And so on (including  `for (int i = low; i <= high; ++i) a[i]=b[i];` )

What you probably want to do is to perform all the assignment to temp storage with a `- low` offset (`b[k-low]` followed by `k++` at the end of the `while` cycle).

Answer (score 0):

I found only a minor problem. Try this simple fix.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; ++i) {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
   }
```

Your code was missing the brackets in the for statement.
This code works on my computer with this fix.